# Using a generic class as a type of java List

Tags: java, generic-programming, generic-list

I would like to create the methode below :

```
    @Override
public List<?> listerUser( Class<?> nomClass ) throws GestionExceptionsDAO {

    Object tableSQL;

    try {
       tableSQL = nomClass.newInstance();
    } catch ( InstantiationException e1 ) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch ( IllegalAccessException e1 ) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<tableSQL> listeUser;//Error : tableSQL cannot be resolved to a type

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query requete = session.createQuery( REQUETE_LIST );
    requete.setParameter( REQUETE_LIST, tableSQL );

    try {
        listeUser = (List<tableSQL>) requete.getResultList();
    } catch ( NoResultException e ) {
        throw null;
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        throw new GestionExceptionsDAO( e );
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return listeUser;
}
```

What I try to do is to create a method which takes in parameter a class name, and returns a list of objects of that class. I think it's simple but I am finding some difficulties to do it. Many thanks.

Comment: As per your description ("create a method which takes in parameter a class name and returns a list of objects of that class") the method's signature should be `<T> List<T> listerUser(Class<T> type)`. See [Generic Methods (The Java™ Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a reference to an instance variable to parametrize a generic type.

The idiom you are probably looking for is the one for a generic method, that returns a `List` parametrized with the type of the given `Class` argument:

```
public <T>List<T> listerUser(Class<T> nomClass) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    // TODO populate the result based on your query 
    return result;
}
```

You can also bind `T` to children or parent of a given class / interface (inclusive upper/lower bounds) by using the `extends` or `super` keywords.

For instance, given a definition of:

```
public <T extends CharSequence>List<T> listerUser( Class<T> nomClass )
```

The invocation could be:

```
List<String> list = listerUser(String.class);
```

**Notes**

- Docs on generic methods [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).
- If you plan on using reflection to initialize a new instance of `T` (e.g. `T t = nomClass.newInstance();`), you'll need to throw or handle `IllegalAccessException` and `InstantiationException`

Comment: Thanks for these explanations but there is something that I can't understand. Why this : `public <T> List<T>` and not just `public List<T>` ?

Comment: @akuma8 that's the generic method idiom syntax: you need to specify the generic type arguments before the actual return type, which cannot otherwise be resolved - see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the same generic parameterized type in the parameter type and the type object returned :

```
   public <T> List<T> listerUser( Class<T> nomClass ) throws GestionExceptionsDAO
```

After you can call it like that:

```
List<String> listerUser = listerUser(String.class);
```